# Excel to find a specific substring within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to extract a string from a cell and I am running into some trouble. In this example I am looking to extract the string `ARM52CVA` from

```
A18031600473 ( FLORENCE - ARM52CVA )
```

Ive tried this formula and it doesnt seem to work for me 
    `=RIGHT(C3,SEARCH("-",C3))`

Answer (score 1):

You would have come closer with either of:

```
=RIGHT(C3,LEN(C3)- SEARCH("-",C3))
=MID(C3,FIND("-",C3)+2,99)
```

but they would have left the ending.

If your data is exactly as you show it, with all of the data and spaces as shown, then try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C3," ",REPT(" ",99)),{1,99,198,297,396},99)),5)
```

If there is more variability, you'll need to show more data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1, 1, FIND("- ", A1)+1, ""), FIND(" ",  REPLACE(A1, 1, FIND("- ", A1)+1, "")), LEN(A1), "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The methods above are far more reliable but ***if*** the white space is consistent you can also use

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+2,(FIND(")",A1,1)-3-FIND("-",A1,1)+1))
```